# Cannot use unisharp/laravel-filemanager's latest version v2.5.1 as it requires ext-exif * which is missing from your platform

Tags: php, laravel

this is my first time using unisharp, i don't know how to upgrade it also i can't seems to find lfm config, i found some solution in the internet which is change it from ^1.8 to the latest version which is did also it says that i should check in my LFM config file and set 'use_package_routes' => true, but i don't know where it is and i have my exif extension enabled in my php.ini too.

here is my composer.json

`

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^4.1",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "^1.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

`

Comment: Enable the `exif` extension in your `php.ini`

Comment: It's already enabled sir

Comment: The error says it's missing. Can you double check it shows up when you run `php -m`

Comment: ahm i think it is enabled, the `extension=exif` it doesn't have a semicolon, is that right? but it doen't show when i run the command `php -m`

Comment: this is the php modules, the result of the command `php -m`

`[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib`

Comment: Always  always, always update your original question with that extra info. It's hard to read in those tiny comments and adding more info to your original question will help improve your question. `php -m [PHP Modules] ` does not contain `exif`

Comment: ow, i'm sorry thanks for that advise, i'll do that for sure, anyways do you know how can i fix this error and install unisharp without this error?